# How do I compile a portable thrift library

Tags: compiler-errors, thrift

I compiled according to the official thrift tutorial, and the command is as follows：

```
./configure --pre=/usr/local/demo/ --with-ruby=no --with-python=no --with-java=no --with-go=no --with-perl=no --with-php=no --with-csharp=no --with-erlang=no --with-lua=no --with-nodejs=no --with-rs=no --with-py3=no CXXFLAGS='-Wno-error' CFLAGS=-fPIE

make 

make install
```

I got thrift's header files and static libraries in /usr/local/demo.
Then I copied the directory to another machine
The test program was compiled, and finally the following error was obtained. If you test directly on the original machine, there is no problem.

I have two questions I'd like your help with

1. Why is this
2. How to solve this error, because my other machine environment lacks the dependency of compiling thrift, so I need this way of porting
   The compiled code looks and error like this

```
Compile command：
g++ -o server HelloService.cpp hello_constants.cpp hello_types.cpp server.cpp -
I/usr/local/demo/include /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a -lpthread

Error:
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(TApplicationException.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(TOutput.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_ZN6apache6thrift7TOutput16errorTimeWrapperEPKc' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(TConcurrentClientSyncInfo.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(TProtocol.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(TTransportException.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(TServerSocket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(TBufferTransports.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(SocketCommon.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(TServerFramework.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/demo/lib/libthrift.a(TSimpleServer.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Comment: The errors all point to symbols that are clearly C++. You set CFLAGS instead of CXXFLAGS.

Comment: I love you. It's the perfect solution to my problem @Botje